# Работа с interbase в FoxPro

Tags: interbase

Есть база `.gdb`. Из нее в таблицу на форму нужно выводить определенные данные. Как я понимаю нужны какие-то библиотеки... Fox вообще вижу 1 раз...( может кто-то помочь или подсказать в каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 0):

Работа с interbase в FoxPro ничем не отличается от работы с любым другим внешним источником данных, например, с MS SQL. Отличаться будет только строка соединения, которую можно сделать с помощью udl файла. Драйверы для доступа к interbase, конечно же, будут нужны, но к фоксу они не имеют отношения и ищутся на ресурсах, посвященных interbase.